# How can I show the album cover with Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is the code to display the page-picture:

```html
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/157295940962451/picture"/>
```

How can I show the album cover of a given album in this page

Answer (score 30):

Not sure if I am doing something wrong, but just wanted to point out that these answers did not work for me until I appended my access_token to the url:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$album['id']?>/picture?type=album&access_token=<?=$access_token?>
```

Comment: @loldop not sure, but I don't see why not. I used this in a fairly large gallery and it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/157295940962451/picture?type=normal
```

> Supported types: small, normal, large,
>   square

---

To get the album cover, you need first to get the album id:

```php
$facebook->api("/PAGE_ID/albums");
```

This should return something like "`PAGEID_ALBUMID`" and then you use the same approach.

Comment: Only thumbnail, normal, album are actually supported for album cover photos, so far as I can see. Asking for small or thumbnail return Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 5):

You can get cover photo directly using below url

http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id or page_id}?fields=cover

---

solution is already posted here
[Getting Facebooks' Cover Photo via PHP SDK & Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125880/getting-facebooks-cover-photo-via-php-sdk-graph-api)

Comment: is there way to get small cover photo (thumbnail) rather then full size one?

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the albums with:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/Your_ID/albums
```

Then you use cover_photo of a given album

```html
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/cover_photo/picture?type=album" alt="" />
```

Supported types: thumbnail, normal, album

Comment: cover_photo is an integer returned in the JSON object by Facebook.  Where are you putting that integer in your url here?

Answer (score 0):

None of those methods worked for me. I found out by accident how to it with the current status of the API, though. Here it is, perform this fql query, replacing the **'token'** with your generated credentials:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?
q=SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE owner = me() &access_token='token'
```

This will return only one picture in the JSON. But, it's the last picture from the first album, which is...the current cover photo. It is the default behaviour. Quite weird, but it solves the problem.