# Retrieving the facebook timeline cover photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos, facebook-timeline

This question has popped up a few times already. I want to retrieve the cover photo of the facebook timeline via the graph api.

The answer that I have seen mentioned everywhere is that it is not possible. However I came across a site http://www.timelinemoviemaker.com/ which does indeed retrieve your cover photo of the timeline. Is there any special permission granted to the site to access the cover photo? Or have they used some other method to retrieve the cover photo. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the album called "Cover Photos". The timeline cover is at position 1
Visit [Getting Facebooks' Cover Photo via PHP SDK & Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125880/getting-facebooks-cover-photo-via-php-sdk-graph-api) to retrieve album covers

Answer (score 8):

Now you can access to the cover picture with the api.

https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552?fields=cover

Comment: how to get Facebook page cover photo

Answer (score 0):

you can access the cover pic from the api using http get response GET/V2.5/me?fields=cover

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  accessToken,
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
      // Insert your code here
    }
});

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "cover");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

but note that u should have the access token generated and registered app in facebook

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way to retrieve your cover photo from Facebook is to right click on the image, select copy image from the pop-up menu, then open up paint, (or whatever program you use for viewing your photos)and then CTL+V for paste.

Comment: The question specified using the graph api.